# pseudo element created with :after is not following the right element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have the following structure, when the label is required, there’s a star next to the label. The problem that I’m having is that if the label has an icon and tooltip inside, it get’s between the label and the star. What could be the possible solution to always have the start right after the label?

```css
.required:after {
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  Label
  <span class="tooltip">
    <i class="icon icon-info"></i>
    <span class="message top">Message</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Well the issue is it will add it as the last element so it will be after the span. can you alter the html and add a span around the text and apply the style to that?

Comment: Put the label text in a `<span>` too and attach the '*' to that.

Comment: You can't select a text node in CSS so as Rene suggests you'll have to wrap it in a span

Comment: Would the tooltip not be positioned absolutely? if that's the case, then it doesn't matter that the asterisk is after it.  If not then the only way to solve it would be to wrap the label text in a span and put the after on that

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example. Your requirements/issues are not totally clear. Please also note that in CSS 3 (since roughly 2010) it's `::after`, not `:after`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where there is an icon in a span element, put the * on a before pseudo element on the direct-child span. It will then come before the contents of that span.

In the case where the label does not have span content, put the * on the after pseudo element on the label.

This can be achieved using CSS :has pseudo class.

```css
.required::after,
.required>span::before {
  content: '*';
}

.required:has(span)::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  Label with span
  <span class="tooltip">
    <i class="icon icon-info"></i>
    <span class="message top">Message</span>
  </span>
</label>
<br>
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  Label no span
</label>
```

If you have to support browsers which do not have the :has implemented then this hack gives the same effect, except there is a character width after the element.

What is does is overlay the * at the end of the label with a little white (or whatever the background color is) rectangle so it is not seen.

```css
.required {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.required>span {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.required::after,
.required>span::before {
  content: '*';
}

.required>span::after {
  content: '*';
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  Label with span
  <span class="tooltip">
    <i class="icon icon-info"></i>
    <span class="message top">Message</span>
  </span>
</label>
<br>
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  Label no span
</label>
```

Comment: I want to cover two cases, and then this approach doesn't work. In case there's no icon, I still want to be able to use the required star on the label.

Comment: I have updated to cover the case where there is no span element. To use this approach though check that all the browsers that matter to your use case implement :has by default (for some versions it is only implemented if a flag is set).

Comment: Also added a hack for if you need to support browsers which haven't implemented :has by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the first solution might be what I am looking for, however I forgot to mention in my question I think that I am using less (just started, never worked with it before) and I'm guessing then the syntax is a bit different? I know I have to add '&' before the selectors but it doesn't really work, since I'm getting  the asterisk in front of the label as well.

Comment: No idea about LESS I'm afraid - I feel safer using pure CSS because I know what's going on!

Comment: It worked fine, after a small tweak. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As described by Rene in his comment, you'll have to put the target text in a span and style that. See example below.

```css
.required > span:first-child:after {
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  <span>Label</span>
  <span class="tooltip">
    <i class="icon icon-info"></i>
    <span class="message top">Message</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: I want to cover two cases, and then this approach doesn't work. In case there's no icon, I still want to be able to use the required star on the label.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution, wrap your `<label>` text in a `<span>` and attach the star to that span:

```css
.required > .text::after {
  content: ' *';
}
```

```html
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  <span class="text">Label</span>
  <span class="tooltip">
    <i class="icon icon-info">Icon</i>
    <span class="message top">Message</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: This works, but not if I want to cover both cases. Since there might be cases when there's no icon component, or any other element, I still want to use the required start on the label.

Answer (score -1):

You could add another span to exclusively contain the star, eg:

```
<label for="input-required" class="required">
  Label
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <span class="tooltip">
    <i class="icon icon-info"></i>
      <span class="message top">Message</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

and alter the new span's display style based on if the label has a required class

```
.star {
  display: none;
}

.required > .star {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Adding additional markup for the task is a bad approach. OP already is working on a better approach using a pseudo element.